# What does "growing from strength to strength" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

as the title asks What does `growing from strength to strength` mean ?
A Google search yields meaning for the word strength and not the phrase. [It would be great if somebody can provide URL/search engine for looking for the meaning of such phrases]

Context

> During my own lifetime our popular cinema has auspiciously grown from
>   strength to strength

Source : [Acceptance speech at the Brisbane Doctorate ceremony](http://www.twitlonger.com/show/dp3cad)

Comment: Can you give the context of where you saw this? Edit your question to add it.

Comment: I have now, looks like its not "exactly the right usage" (it should be `gone from strength to strength`, but I am not 100% sure about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.google.com/search?q=define+from+strength+to+strength

yields

http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/144200.html

> Meaning
>
> Progress from one success to another higher level of success. Origin
>
> From the Miles Coverdale's Version of the Bible, Psalms 84:7:
>
> ```
> They go from strength to strength and so the God of Gods apeareth vnto the in Sion.
> ```

Comment: thanks, I never thought of using `define` tag for phrases.

Answer (score 2):

I think the customary phrase is *going from strength to strength*, rather that *growing...* (the former phrase is the one I hear more often and has four times as many Google results, for what that's worth).

Other than that I can't add anything to mplungjan's answer.

Comment: I have provided the context, so it looks like it is (accidental, if my assume) wrong usage, but the meaning is the same

Answer (score 0):

A Brit Box tv show from England called Escape to the Country says this, “the county has 145 old world trees registered that are growing strength to strength.”  Meaning they were incredibly old and they had been declared immune to disease and unusually strong in character and type.

Comment: Hello Joni, this is probably better suited as a comment than an answer. Also, a 7-year-old question with an accepted answer generally should be considered as solved. There's plenty more recent questions that need answering!

Answer (score -2):

to gain more in knowledge and to accept things that seem not possible and to add power to meaning of will meaning the will to do and not the wrong way of life to get ahead what won1t kill you can make you stronger=strength to strength